# Client error after installing custom certificate

Tags: ssl, cisco-asa

I've followed (I believe) all the right steps to install a trusted certificate on my ASA firewall:

- install company root authority into ASA as a CA
- issue a certificate for the ASA's hostname
- install the certificate into ASA as an identity certificate
- apply the certificate to the outside interface

However, I continue to get this error in the browser when trying to connect:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to asa.xxx.internal. SSL was unable to extract the public key from the peer’s certificate.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_EXTRACT_PUBLIC_KEY_FAILURE

I've verified with `show crypto certificates` that the certificate has been imported correctly and shows as associated with the imported CA.

The only thing I'm doing here that isn't 100% familiar to me is working with EC certificates instead of RSA, but it doesn't seem like that should have any bearing.

Relevant parts of `show run`:

```
hostname asa
domain-name xxx.internal
http server enable
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint0
 enrollment terminal
 validation-usage ipsec-client ssl-client ssl-server
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpoint ASDM_TrustPoint1
 keypair ASDM_TrustPoint1
 no validation-usage
 crl configure
crypto ca trustpool policy
 auto-import
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint0
 certificate ca 4e7bf88d72c08d4efa48d3ec658e5a3281b2c6aa
    3082028e 30820233 a0030201 0202144e 7bf88d72 b08d4efa 48d3ec65 8e5a3281 
    ...
 quit
crypto ca certificate chain ASDM_TrustPoint1
 certificate c47d26f97ee247a9
    308203d8 3082037e a0030201 02020900 c47d26f9 7ee247a7 300a0608 2a8648ce 
    ...
  quit
 certificate ca 4e7bf88d72c08d4efa48d3ec658e5a3281b2c6aa
    3082028e 30820233 a0030201 0202144e 7bf88d72 b08d4efa 48d3ec65 8e5a3281 
  quit
ssl server-version tlsv1.2
ssl trust-point ASDM_TrustPoint1 outside
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out eventually (fun way to spend a Saturday.)

I connected with `openssl s_client` to see what was happening and from the output I pulled out an error message:

> Verification error: Certificate public key has explicit ECC parameters

So, I'm not sure how to resolve that issue. I'm generating the key and issuing the cert per [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/190646/56261) on the Information Security SE. The default is supposed to be named curves, not explicit parameters but even if I set the value I was still getting the same result.

---

I'll figure that out later but in the meantime, what I ended up having to do was generate a key on the ASA, and export it to do the cert generation. This is [a bit hacky](https://www.fragmentationneeded.net/2015/04/exporting-rsa-keys-from-cisco-asa.html) but it worked:

```
crypto key generate ecdsa label my_private_key elliptic-curve 384
crypto ca trustpoint throwaway
  keypair mykey
  enrollment self
  exit
crypto ca enroll throwaway noconfirm
crypto ca export throwaway pkcs12 foo
no crypto ca trustpoint throwaway noconfirm
```

At this point I had a base64 PKCS #12 bag on the terminal. I copied the base64 data (**not** including the BEGIN and END lines) to my server and did this to get the key:

```shell
echo "MIIEDwIBAzCCA8UGC..." | base64 -d | \
  openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -nodes -password pass:foo > my.key
```

Success, I have the key! I generated the certificate using it, and created a new trustpoint using the keypair from earlier:

```
crypto ca trustpoint my_tls_certificate
  enrollment terminal
  no ca-check
  subject-name CN=asa.xxx.internal
  keypair my_private_key
  exit
crypto ca enroll my_tls_certificate noconfirm
crypto ca import my_tls_certificate certificate
```

At this point I provided the certificate file (again without the BEGIN and END lines) followed by "quit" on a line by itself.

Finally I was able to enable the certificate with `ssl trust-point my_tls_certificate outside` and connect successfully.